# Configuring bash to prevent rm -rf * from being run without warning in ~/

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm running the most recent Ubuntu Linux.

This morning I ran a script that did quite a few things. While doing these things, for reasons I have not yet got round to investigating, the script came back up one directory too many and did a 
rm -rf *
in directory 
~/
Obviously not good; I spend 3 hours restoring and re-configuring everything.

Question: What would a function inside .bashrc look like that would always user prompt, even from a script that has not user input, whenever it saw 
rm -rf ~/*
or
rm -rf * while in directory ~/

Comment: Yes, our old friend, 'rm * .o' - oops... been there...

Comment: So you basically want to unforce the force option when it's in certain directories? I'm interested to see any answers...

Comment: Yes, that's what I asked if you read correctly. Sometimes in life workarounds can exist in different problems

Comment: To match only `rm -rf *` can't be done. Any wrapper you put around `rm` will only see the post-expansion argument list; it won't know if that came from a `*` or from typing each filename out individually.

Comment: Anyhow, there are much more comprehensive solutions already available: Use a filesystem or block store with snapshot support, so you can look at your files as they existed as of some prior point in time. btrfs does this, ZFS does this... heck, AFS was doing it back in the 90s (and OpenAFS after that).

Comment: BTW, in the future, [unix.se] might be a better forum for this kind of question, being arguably more about interactive shell configuration than about software development.

Comment: Be careful when you change the default interface of standard commands. Once a sysop had an `alias rm=rm -i` installed in my all users profile. One day I was root and wanted to remove some files. My `rm *`, expecting confirmation for each file, was a mistake.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I read about ex4 vs BTFRS a long time ago. However at your prompting I went off to investigate last night again. BTFRS, snapper.io & hourly snap shots would have helped me enormously yesterday. I run a SSD which might not like the hourly writes. However a rolling snapshot of ~/ every hour, keeping a max of 2 snapshots would have been ideal and saved me. I  could create a 'snap' outside of ~/ so it's protected. I will think on this: the balance is between this being the next step forward from ex4 and such an unintended  deletion only happening once in a very long while.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interestingly I could then also do diffs on the current snapshot and the current ~/ which would really help with the file version confusion I sometimes have, though generally dropbox web meets this need.

Comment: @walter-a The change is only for my system

Comment: @Kes, I believe Walter's point is that if you develop habits based on customizations you've only made to your own system, you don't want to mistakenly do something destructive when you're on a different machine/account because the practices you've made a habit of no longer apply.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is right, I do not want someone with such habits/functions/aliases help me with a problem on my machine/account.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think the point is over laboured. I would not intentionally delete ~/ anywhere. This protects me here and now. I'm not planning for a different machine, that does not yet exist, and has differet settings. I will deal with the future when it arrives. The here and now is a full enough plate for anyone.

Comment: @Kes, I'm speaking as someone with decades of experience as a sysadmin (before moving to a more development-focused role) -- finger memory reliant on machine-local customization is a way people make mistakes, and sometimes those mistakes are expensive. You're free to ignore advice, but it's easier to avoid getting such painful experiences firsthand.

Comment: (A few jobs ago we had a bug caused by someone being sloppy in their quoting because nothing in a directory could "possibly ever" have a filename with nothing but hex digits -- then bad pointer handling in a C library used by a Python program creating files in that directory dumped in names with garbage, and the shell script in question deleted multiple TB of billing-data backups. This was sysadmin staff who'd been in the business for a long time, and let themselves get lax about best practices because they hadn't been burnt in person -- but when one *does* get burnt, you can get burnt hard).

Comment: @Kes, ...and no, the code here **doesn't** protect you, for the reasons I previously described and others. It can check `$PWD`, but that won't stop `rm -rf ~ /foo` instead of `rm -rf ~/foo` if you're running it from a directory other than `~`. Similarly, if you're assuming that `export -f rm` will mean your wrapper is run by subprocess, you may someday run a command with, say, vim's `!rm`, and find that it used `/bin/sh` rather than `bash` and so didn't read the function. If a false sense of safety stops you from implementing backups, you're worse off than you would have been without it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure where to begin. This is big wide ranging topic about best practice, there would be lots to discuss to get an understanding with each other, and I just don't have time. I have enough to cope with. I wish I did have that time becasue your experience clearly has much to offer. Is best practice for pro sys admin the same as best practice for my debian? Look around you at any computer user for the answer. I'm not a system admin and have no plans for becoming a sys admin in the future; I do know that on systems that handle valuable billing data sys admin is a very (cont'd)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy (cont'd) significant role. It's a significant role on any system where there are a number of users.
If I could offer some advice back it's this. I am here simply for what I asked for. After decades in science I learnt one thing really well; never take on board the periphery esoteric that is the "more than you need". You end up in hospital. It's a much bigger lesson than best practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Thank you for your comments. Having taken more time to reflect on these they make a lot of sense. I had to get away for a while; family stuff. I don't feel inclined to going back to using rm -rf. I'm thinking of using mv and a temp folder in another profile instead. (After various reading i'm not sure BTFRS is ready?) I don't know if there is an answer to the question as I put it. I have received lots of informed experience here, and I would like there to be an answer somehow if possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could place a custom `rm` in your `PATH` and make it call `/bin/rm` with `-i` forced into its argument array as the last option, something like (only considers POSIX flags):

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
if [ "$PWD" != "$HOME" ]; then 
    exec /bin/rm "$@"
    exit 127
fi
opts=
while getopts 'fiRr' opt; do
    case $opt in [fiRr]) opts=$opts$opt;; *) exit 1;; esac
done; 
shift $((OPTIND-1))
/bin/rm -${opts}i "$@" < /dev/tty
```

Comment: Does this address the only-in-`$HOME` part of the question?

Comment: (it *does* cover something I didn't, which is to say, overriding any explicit `-f` by making sure that a `-i` comes *last* among options).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I had missed that in the question.  Added now.

Comment: Very useful thanks @PSkocik. Your programing skills are way beyond mine. Could you provide a few words around the script? Today I'm not well disposed to executing anything I don't fully understand; otherwise I will look at it in the morning when it may well make sense to me. It's 130am here.

Comment: @Kes The if condition should be clear . `exec /bin/rm "$@"` replaces the scripts's process images with that of `/bin/rm`, and the script fails with 127 (a convention) if this replacement fails. The next part tries to parse out the POSIX flags `-f`, `-i`, `-R`, `-r`, savng them into opts (without the hyphen). `shift $((OPTIND-1))` then shifts the arguments so that the parsed flags move out. The remainder's in `"$@"`. The flags are then passed to /bin/rm with `i` added  to them (so that it overrides possible `-f`) , followed by the non-flaggy arguments.

Comment: @Kes Finally, the `< /dev/tty` redirects the controlling terminal to `rm`'s `stdin`, making sure the answer to its prompt is read from the terminal, even if the surrounding script running this fake `rm` is using a file as its `stdin`.

Comment: @Kes It's a good thing you don't trust it. The utmost care should always be exercised when dealing with stuff from stranger, especially if it plays with `rm` a lot. :)

Comment: @PSkocik Can this bash code simply be wrapped in a function and placed in .bashrc? Needless to say my tests will not be on ~/

Comment: @Kes If you want to be able to run it from a script, you need an executable, not a function. (Relying on bash's `export -f`,, it'd be doable with a function as long as you only had shell scripts running in bash, but it would require some modifications to the code.)

Answer (score 1):

Prompt is a weak way to prevent this from happening. It's very easy to get used to hitting the same response all the time whenever you want to delete something without thinking too much.

It's much better to implement a trashcan of sorts that you can recover files from.

You can alias rm with an mv command to a 'trash-can' where you can schedule a cron job to clean this trashcan regularly.

Maybe alias rm with something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
mvargs=()
i=0
for arg in "$@"
do
    case "$arg" in

            -r|-R)
                shift;;

            -rf|-Rf |-R|-fr|-fR)
                mvargs[$i]="-f"
                ((++i))
                shift;;

            *)

                mvargs[$i]="$arg"
                ((++i))
                shift;;
    esac
done

mv "${mvargs[@]}" "/tmp/trashcan"
```

Where /tmp/trashcan is a possible trashcan

Comment: I'm not the best at bash scripting, if anyone has any comments on how to parse for the -r option more elegantly, I'm open to advice

Comment: One thing to note is that this won't handle `rm -- -r`, which actually deletes a file named `-r`, rather than treating the string `-r` as an option.

Comment: Also, `mvargs+=( "$arg" )` is an easier way of appending to an array (doesn't require maintaining a counter).